# Finding quotient of $7/5^3=Exp(2\pi i 7/5^3)\in Z(5^{\infty})$ by $20$ or 20-th root

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find quotient of $7/5^3=Exp(2\pi i 7/5^3)\in Z(5^{\infty})$ by $20$ or in other words, find 20-th root of $7/5^3$ in $Z(5^{\infty})$.

The troublesome part is $(20,5)=5$. So I cannot use coprimeness of $7$ and $20$ to generate 1 naively. How should I find such an element systematically?

Comment: The equation $7/5^3=\exp(2\pi i7/5^3)$ is false and silly. I presume you are identifying the elements $7/5^3$ in $\Bbb Z[1/5]/\Bbb Z$ with the corresponding element in $S^1$, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the Prufer $5$-group $\mathbb{Z}(5^\infty)=\mathbb{Z}[1/5]/\mathbb{Z}$ is a module over the $5$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Calculating a fourth root amounts to multiplying by the $5$-adic number $1/4$, which can be expanded by a geometric series using the fact that $4=5-1$. This is equivalent to computing $4^{-1}$ mod sufficiently high powers of $5$ to subsquently multiply against an element of $\mathbb{Z}(5^\infty)$.